# Prepare list of integer at compilation

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I have a list of integer which holds color values.
I use it to fill a custom color picker.

It looks like this:

```
Public ColorTable As New List(Of Integer)
```

And I need to fill it somewhere, so I call this when my application starts:

```
Public Sub InitColorTable()

    ColorTable.Add(16777215) '0
    ColorTable.Add(13421823) '1
    ColorTable.Add(10079487) '2
    ColorTable.Add(10092543) '3
    ColorTable.Add(13434879) '4
    ColorTable.Add(10092441) '5
```

This doesn't look very professional to me.

Is there a way to compile this list at compilation time so that it's already available at program start even without the above initialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a [collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/collection-initializers/):

```
Public ColorTable As New List(Of Integer) From 
    {16777215, 13421823, 10079487, 10092543, 13434879, 10092441}
```

Alternatively, keep the `InitColorTable()` method and use it to load your values from a config file or database.